# How can I get the order of startup scripts - upstart and systemV

Tags: bash, services, upstart, cloud-init, sysv

I have an upstart script that must start before a non-upstart (System V) script.
I see that while booting, the systemV script starts before my upstart script.
How can I check the boot order of these scripts? Do all systemV scripts start before upstart scripts?
What options do I have to make sure this upstart script starts before the systemV script, other than converting my upstart script to a systemV script?

Comment: That’s a good question and you got my upvote already, but please allow the question: Why don’t you just use one solely, preferably [systemd](https://askubuntu.com/a/719157/507051)?

Comment: Because I am using an upstart based system. And the systemV scripts come as part of some of the packages that I depend on.